# Rank elements in a sequence in clojure

Tags: clojure, sequence, seq

I have a sequence on elements like 
`([:Jon 326] [:Mary 233] [:Matthew 255])`

and would like to transform this sequence in a clever way into something like a map of 
`{{:name Jon :rank 1} {:name Matthew :rank 2} {:name Mary :rank 3}}`

:name should be a string type and :rank an integer

The rank is calculated by the number, comparing to the others in the elements in the sequence, the higher the "points" higher the rank

Comment: Your result map contains the `:rank` key multiple times - do you want a sequence of maps e.g. `({:name Jon :rank 1} {:name Matthew :rank 2} {:name Mary :rank 3})`? Do you want the `:name` values to be symbols? How are the `:rank` values calculated?

Comment: Sorry for the error when writting the map, It must be a sequence of maps. The :name Key should be a string and the :rank os calculated from the number in the sequence eg. ([:Jon 255][:Mary 150]) Jon is rank 1 And Mary rank 2 because Jon has 255 points ans Mary 150 points

Comment: @br-baker-01 You should edit the question then.

Comment: @AmanuelNega thanks for the help edited the question for clarification

Answer (score 7):

You can use `sort-by` to order the input sequence and then use `map-indexed` to convert it into a rank:

```
(def input '([:Jon 326] [:Mary 233] [:Matthew 255]))

(map-indexed (fn [idx p]
               {:name (name (first p))
                :rank (inc idx)})
             (sort-by second > input))
```

or you can use the thread-last macro:

```
 (->> input 
      (sort-by second >) 
      (map-indexed (fn [idx p] {:name (name (first p)) :rank (inc idx)})))
```

you could also destructure the pair in the function to `map-indexed` instead of using `first`:

```
(->> input 
     (sort-by second >) 
     (map-indexed (fn [idx [n _]] {:name (name n) :rank (inc idx)})))
```